# SharePoint, notification email workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-workflow

I was wondering if anyone could possibly help me with my SharePoint 2010 issue. I recently created a CRM System within SharePoint for my small business which utilizes a email notification workflow. The workflow is triggered when the 'Action Needed' field has a 'yes' value, this means that 2 days after the information is created or edited the workflow will notify the particular user that further action is needed.

[Previous thread with image of the workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85026/grouped-notification-email-workflow)

[image: Workflow]

Now this is great if myself or other members of the team are only inputting a couple of items but I found out the hard way when i keyed in 20 or so items and received 20 individual emails which is irritating as you can imagine.

So on to my issue, I would like the email notifications to be grouped together in one email so it's more efficient and avoids the need for individual emails. So when one particular user creates or edits multiple records instead of separate email notifications I would like it all in one email. So is this possible while using SharePoint workflows? If it is possible and how would I go about expanding my current workflow to achieve this?

I have already asked this question in the dedicated SharePoint area to no prevail, I could really do with the help also if what I am asking is impossible then could someone at least say so.

Thanks very much to anyone who contributes and helps me with my problem.

Comment: what exactly did you tried?

Comment: Currently I have a working workflow which is as follows, 

IF Current Item:Action Needed equals yes
  Pause for 2 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes 
  then Email CurrentItem:User Email

This works but doesn't handle exactly what I need done, I want email notifications to be grouped together if a team member has created/edited more than one item within the CRM.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint Designer , then this is not problem. This is because each workflow can access the data on which List Item the workflow is triggered.

However, this is definitely possible using a custom workflow or an event Receiver.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437502(v=office.14).aspx